# Error 500 while deploying my Flask app with mo_wsgi on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask, web-deployment, mod-wsgi

I am currently trying to deploy a very basic Flask app on my ubuntu VPS with mod_wsgi.

I followed this youtube tutorial as precisely as I could : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0QDAg85Oow

But i ended up with a 500 error. Here is a sample from the logs :

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=8283): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/flask-app/app.wsgi'.
 mod_wsgi (pid=8283): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flask-app/app.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/flask-app/app.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
     with open(activate_this) as file_:
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/flask-app-yYmzn1cG/bin/activate_this.py'
```

The app.wsgi file :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/flask-app')

activate_this = '/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/flask-app-yYmzn1cG/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from app import app as application
```

The python app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The flask-app.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask-app/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/flask-app>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/flask-app/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/flask-app/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Screenshot from apache2 both /etc/apache2/sites-available and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAeIQ.png)

As we can see in the logs it seems to be a permission error.
What I understood from the video and the flask documentation (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/) is that the server runs my app with the "www-data" user as we told him in the flask-app.conf :

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
```

What i've tried for the moment is to run from root :

```
$ chown -R www-data:www-data /root/.local/share/virtualenvs
```

Because i created my pipenv virtual env with root, i tried to give the ownership from these to the www-data user.

But the error still remains...

I just begin with VPS, apache and Flask and I can't find a solution for this problem.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I tried to create a new user called "arnaud", and i copied the "flask-app-yYmzn1cG" folder (containing the virtualenv) in /home/arnaud/flask-app-venv.

I changed the path of the "activate_this.py" in the app.wsgi file to point the new /home/arnaud/flask-app-venv/flask-app-yYmzn1cG/bin/activate_this.py.

I changed "user" and "group" to "arnaud" in the flask-app.conf.

**...and this worked. No error this time and my app is running.**

So the problem was for the user "www-data" to access the pipenv generated virtual env in the /root/ (owned by root) folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that mod_wsgi actually runs as the www-data user? If you start the application from a non-privileged user (and without sudo), mod_wsgi won't be able to switch to the www-data user.
I can't say for mod_wsgi, but IIRC uwsgi would just silently just run as the invoking user if it didn't have the required permission to run it as the configured user.